# need rails like form_for tag in Rhodes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rhomobile, rhodes

I was wondering if I can have something like `form_for` tag instead of the html  tag in the `edit.erb` page in `Rhodes`. Because I have a `Counter` model with two attribs which I want to update them seperately based on the button pressed which resides right beside the value. I was able to do it in rails using the `<%= form.submit 'up_a' %>` & check which button was pressed in update method, like:

```
def update    
  @counter = Counter.find(params[:id])  
  if params[:commit] == 'up_a'       
    update_attri1    # simple increment method  for attrib 1
  elsif params[:commit] == 'up_b'       
    update_attri2    # simple increment method for attrib 2
  end   
end
```

and call that method to update that value.

So I want to have more control on what attribs I want to update based 
on the clicks in form. Is there anyway I can achieve this in Rhodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :**

The general problem seems to be that you want two submit buttons in a single form, each of which should do two slightly different things.

In the case that you only have two different values and one submit button for each, the simplest solution would be simply to make two forms that both call the `update` def (through their action-attribute), but each with their specific value of the query-parameter (in this case "commit"). These calls would have the following form:

```
<form method="POST" class="myForm" action="<%=url_for :controller => :Counter, :action => :update, :query => {:commit => 'up_a'}%>">
```

However, if you only want a single form (possibly also with many other input-values) there are several different ways to do it. In the following you will see a detailed implementation of one way to do it.

In this solution your buttons should NOT be submit buttons, but regular buttons (exactly how they are made with jQuery Mobile).

In order to make this solution work, you will need to use some javascript. You should therefore add the following javascript functions to your `application.js` and include it in your `layout.erb`.

```
function submitForm(formClass){
    var activeForm = 'div.ui-page-active '+formClass;
    $(activeForm).submit();
}
function callCounterSetUpdateAction(c){
    $.get('/app/Counter/setUpdateAction', { commit: c});
}
```

Now that we have the needed javascript functions in place, lets take a look at `edit.erb`.

In this example Counter have three different attributes: a, b and c. We will however, only pay attention to a and b to begin with.

The form in your `edit.erb` file should be similar the implementation below. Notice, that the form actually doesn't have a submit button (as we will see later, the submit is actually made through our javascript function `submitForm(formClass)`).

```
<form method="POST" class="myForm" action="<%= url_for :action => :update %>">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= @counter.object %>"/>

      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="counter[a]" class="fieldLabel">A</label>
        <input type="text" id="counter[a]" name="counter[a]" value="<%= @counter.a %>" <%= placeholder( "A" ) %> />
      </div>

      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="counter[b]" class="fieldLabel">B</label>
        <input type="text" id="counter[b]" name="counter[b]" value="<%= @counter.b %>" <%= placeholder( "B" ) %> />
      </div>

      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="counter[c]" class="fieldLabel">C</label>
        <input type="text" id="counter[c]" name="counter[c]" value="<%= @counter.c %>" <%= placeholder( "C" ) %> />
      </div>
      <a data-role="button" data-transition="none" href="javascript:callCounterSetUpdateAction('up_a');">Update A</a>
      <a data-role="button" data-transition="none" href="javascript:callCounterSetUpdateAction('up_b');">Update B</a>
</form>
```

Now that we have defined our view (`edit.erb`) lets take a look at the definitions we need our controller.

Firsly, as it can be seen from the `href` attribute on the buttons, what actually happens once we press a button is that it calls a javascript function which in turn calls the following `def` in the controller:

```
def setUpdateAction
  $pressedButton = @params['commit']
  WebView.execute_js("submitForm('.myForm');")
end
```

The purpose of this `def` is to store the parameter we sent from our button and then submit the form on the active page. Notice here that we added a `class` called `myForm` to the form shown above. You should also notice that we ensure that only the form on the active page is selected by adding `'div.ui-page-active '` to our `formClass` in the jQuery selection.

Finally, lets take a look at how your `update` definition should look like:

```
def update
@counter = Counter.find(@params['id'])
c = @params['counter']
if @counter
  if $pressedButton == 'up_a'
    # Update value  A.
    @counter.update_attributes(
      {"a" => c['a']}
    )
  elsif $pressedButton == 'up_b'
    # Update value  B.
    @counter.update_attributes(
              {"b" => c['b']}
            )
  end
end
redirect :action => :index
end
```

It should be noticed here that we select which attributes to update based upon the `$pressedButton` variable we assigned through `setUpdateAction`. As a final comment we could also update multiple attributes as seen below (where we also update the 'c' attribute).

```
@counter.update_attributes(
              {"b" => c['b'],"c" => c['c']}
            )
```

Comment: Do you recieve the parameter in your `def` ? If so, you may only need to refresh your page. In either case your [here](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhomobile-docs/blob/master/docs/rhodes/application.txt) is a reference to some advanced ways to use :url_for and :link_to statements.

Comment: In case you need to refresh your page and want to avoid it, you can write a simple javascript function which you can execute with parameters directly from your controller like this:  `WebView.execute_js("incrementField('a');")`.

Comment: but I dont know how can the db entry gets updated when we invoke js. Please Im really bad(newbie) at this

Comment: I have now replaced my answer with a full implementation of how to do it (which is tested on an Android device). I have tried to explain it along the way, if you have any further questions fell free to ask.

Comment: Whao!!! I think you should write a book on this. Never got any this comprehensive explanation ever!!! Thanks a ton Corthmann! I am trying to implement the exact incrementer operation now :)